# How to redue distance between two rows of BrowseFragment

Tags: android, leanback, browsefragment

I am using BrowseFragment with no Zooming effect as below:

```
ListRowPresenter presenter = new ListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE, true);
```

Due to this I'm having extra space between end and start of another row. As shown in image (highlighted in red box).

[image]

How can I reduce this space?

I had already tried overriding following dimensions, but it has no effect:

```
<dimen name="lb_browse_padding_bottom">48dp</dimen>
<dimen name="lb_browse_padding_end">56dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can adjust thiese margins via overriding following values:

```
<dimen name="lb_browse_expanded_selected_row_top_padding">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="lb_browse_expanded_row_no_hovercard_bottom_padding">28dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how do you know this? How can you tell which name and value to override for which fragment?

Comment: Its there in leanback SDK. Each property affects the respective part on screen. Check out this for more information: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/882ee91503f28d1fd60ba939c5b37db6b9d4ad29/sdk/extras/android/support/v17/leanback/res/values/dimens.xml

Comment: this is a great starting point, thank you very much